# Cannot get checkJwt middleware to work for multiple origins in expressJS server

Tags: express, jwt, auth0

I am trying to handle routing for two separate websites that share a server between the two. Some routes are shared amongst the sites while others I only want to provide API access to based off of their token.

I wrote middleware to check the origin of the incoming request called `checkAuthorization`, it is suppose to verify a token based off of its site origin, **I keep getting the 401 response error for site B but NOT site A**:

`InvalidTokenError`

`error_description=Invalid Compact JWS`

I do not get this error when using `checkJwtA` or `checkJwtB` in my routes.
**jwt-check.ts middleware file**

```
import express, { Request, Response, NextFunction } from 'express';
import { auth, requiredScopes } from 'express-oauth2-jwt-bearer';

export const checkJwtB2B = auth({  //used for website B tokens
    audience: '**********',
    issuerBaseURL: '**********',
    tokenSigningAlg: 'RS256',
});

export const checkJwtB2C = auth({  //used for website A tokens
  audience: '**********',
  issuerBaseURL: '**********',
  tokenSigningAlg: 'RS256',
});
  

//  partially works for some routes.
export const checkAuthorization = async (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
  try {
    if(req.headers.origin === 'http://localhost:3000'){ //website A origin
      console.log('check b2c auth')
      return checkJwtB2C(req, res, next);

    }else if ( req.headers.origin === 'http://localhost:6060') { //website B origin
      console.log('checking b2b auth')
      return checkJwtB2B(req, res, next);
    }
  } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
      res.status(401).json({ message: 'Unauthorized' });
  }
 next();
}
```

The strange thing is, I use `checkAuthorization` works for website A, but not for website B.
Also, `checkAuthorization` seems to work in my root server.ts file for the route

```
app.get('/api/v1/tags', checkAuthorization, async (req:Request, res:Response) =>{ // both websites A & B call this route and it is successfull
```

**notificaions.ts file**

```
notificationRoutes.get('/:provId', checkAuthorization, //route using checkAuthorization for website B, does not work
```

**b2c-notifications.ts file**

```
b2cNotificationRoutes.get('/:b2cId', checkAuthorization, // same middle ware, works for website A
```

It appears that `checkAuthorization` is working for only the first conditional `req.headers.origin === 'http://localhost:3000'` which is website A and not for  website B which is
`req.headers.origin === 'http://localhost:6060'`

i'm using `"@auth0/auth0-react": "^2.2.1",` for both clients and `"express-oauth2-jwt-bearer": "^1.5.0",` for my backend jwt verification.

below is my **server.ts** file

```
const app: Express = express();
dayjs.extend(customParseFormat);

const port = process.env.SERVER_PORT || 4200;
app.use(router);
app.use(helmet({
    hsts: {
      maxAge: 31536000,
    },
    contentSecurityPolicy: {
      useDefaults: false,
      directives: {
        "default-src": ["'none'"],
        "frame-ancestors": ["'none'"],
      },
    },
    frameguard: {
      action: "deny",
    },
  })
);
app.use(cors({credentials: true, origin: ['http://localhost:3000', 'http://localhost:6060']})); //TODO deploy set proper URLS
app.use(express.json());
app.use(handler);

app.get('/api/v1/tags', checkAuthorization, async (req:Request, res:Response) =>{
  ....//works for both site A and B
});

app.post('/api/v1/tags/suggestions', checkAuthorization, async (req: Request, res: Response) => { 
  ....//works for both site A and B
})

app.use('/api/v1/providers', providerRoutes);
app.use('/api/v1/notification', notificationRoutes);
app.use('/api/v1/employer', employerRoutes);
app.use('/api/v1/job', jobRoutes);
app.use('/api/v1/individual', individualRoutes);
app.use('/api/b2c/user', b2cUserRoutes);
app.use('/api/b2c/job', b2cJobRoutes);
app.use('/api/b2c/activity', b2cActivityRoutes);
app.use('/api/b2c/notification', b2cNotificationRoutes);
```